# Why can't I get @EnableLoadTimeWeaving in spring boot web with embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

I am writing a spring boot web application packaged as a executable jar file and I need load time AspectJ weaving. Using `-javaagent` is not an option for me as it will require our DevOps to change the deployment toolchain, which I don't want to deal with right now. Here is my Main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
    return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
  }
}
```

This did not work. I thought maybe injecting `InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver` is not playing well with embedded Tomcat. I tried replacing it with `TomcatLoadTimeWeaver`. But the result was that spring context failed to load with the following error message.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize TomcatLoadTimeWeaver because Tomcat API classes are not available

[This bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/739) on spring-boot github issues concludes that currently AspectJ load time weaving cannot be used with embedded tomcat. My question is why is it not possible? I want to understand what is the load time weaving mechanism which makes it impossible to work in an executable Spring boot web jar.

Comment: Try to add this dependebcy [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument-tomcat/4.3.6.RELEASE)

Comment: Were you able to solve?

Comment: Not yet my friend, but someday!